# How to compute U Eα and ∩Eα.

Tags: real-analysis

Eα = [0, α) ∩ Q = {r ∈ Q : 0 ≤ r < α} for each
α ∈ (0, 1). 
Compute  U Eα and  ∩Eα.

I tried to solve this problem with the sequence of α.

Guess the first one is [0,1) ∩ Q and the other {0}

Is there any hint to figure it out with concept of openness or interior points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition,

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,1)}E_\alpha=\left\{\,r\in\Bbb Q\;|\;0\le r<\alpha\,,\,\text{for some}\;\;\alpha\in[0,1)\,\right\}=[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$$

Or also

$$x\in[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q\implies0\le x<1,\,\text{and}\,x\in\Bbb Q\implies \exists\alpha\in[0,1) \left(\text{ for example}\,\alpha=x+\frac{1-x}2=\frac{x+1}2\right)$$

$$\text{s.t.}\;0\le x<\alpha\implies x\in E_\alpha\implies x\in\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,1)}E_\alpha$$

About the intersection:

$$x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in[0,1)}E_\alpha\implies\forall0\le\alpha<1\;,\;\;0\le x<1\;\text{and}\;x\in\Bbb Q\implies x=0$$

or also

$$0<x<1\;\text{and}\;x\in\Bbb Q\implies \exists \alpha\in (0,1)\;\left(\text{for example}\;\alpha'=\frac x2\right)\;\text{s.t.}$$

$$x\notin E_{\alpha'}\implies x\notin\bigcap_{\alpha\in[0,1)}E_\alpha$$

So you were right...

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I was wondering if I should use density of rationals.. but couldn't find any points during figuring out

Comment: @anonym That could make things slightly easier, of course. For example, if $\;0<x<1\;$ then there is a real $\;r\,,\,\,0<r<x\;$ and a real $\;s\,,\,x<s<1\;$ ...